# Viewing test results for a failure on bamboo

Tags: selenium, automation, bamboo, bamboo-artifacts, bamboo-specs

I run the test on bamboo with selenium technology and the test tab does not show the test failure, how I can view the test failure?

[image: bamboo screenshot]

Comment: Bamboo 5.15.5 version build 5151

Answer (score 1):

To see test results (including info which test caused fail) you need to add proper parser task to your job. There are many available parser tasks i.e. JUnit Parser, NUnit Parser, TestNG Parser.

The important thing is to **move parser task under *Final tasks* bar** (parser will execute even if previous task fail).

Comment: Thank you! I missed the "Final Tasks" bar.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any test failures. In fact, no tests were running in this build as you can see in line

> **0** test in total

You job may have failed for one of 2 reasons:

1. Actual failure of the job. Check detailed log on Logs tab to see if this is the case
2. It may have also failed because you configured it to fail when there was no tests (and in this case there was no tests indeed) as we see. The corresponding configuration would look like this:

[image]